# Maximum size for SRT subtitles

Tags: subtitle, srt

For a project I'm going to extend the concept of subtitle to embed information inside a video. I would use the SRT format.

**Note:** My subtitles are not intended to be shown. They are useful (and meaningful) for my software only.

The [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip) of SRT is well-known and pretty simple:

1. A numeric counter identifying each sequential subtitle
2. The time that the subtitle should appear on the screen, followed by --> and the time it should disappear
3. Subtitle text itself on one or more lines
4. A blank line containing no text, indicating the end of this subtitle

Such a specification is incomplete: there are no indications about the maximum lengths of each line and the maximum numbers of lines.

Doing a Google search I find a lot of "guidelines" about how to write good subtitles (i.e. avoid more than N chars per line, etc...) , but I don't find anything that states the actual limits.

Comment: There are no limits that I know of.

Comment: @Smile4ever yours should be an answer rather a comment :-)

Answer (score 4):

There are no limits in line width or size (number of lines) that I know of.

The only thing that exists are recommendations:

- using maximum 47 characters per line
- per subtitle a maximum of two or three lines

In your use case, this shouldn't matter, because these guidelines only exist for displaying subtitles. As long as the software can read the SRT-file, you are fine.

Sources:

- https://www.capitalcaptions.com/services/subtitle-services-2/capital-captions-standard-subtitling-guidelines/
- https://bbc.github.io/subtitle-guidelines/

Comment: Is there a source where I can find this statement?